# Automating project creation in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

If you straight-forward create a project in Visual Studio (let's say a console application) by clicking on "Console Application Project" in the project wizard and name it appropriately, it usually results in the following file structure:

```
MyCompany.MyProject\
    MyCompany.MyProject.csproj
    MyCompany.MyProject.sln
```

There's an option for creating an extra folder for the solution, which results in...

```
MyCompany.MyProject\
    MyCompany.MyProject.sln
    MyCompany.MyProject\
        MyCompany.MyProject.csproj
```

Both of them are undesireable because they lead to problems with long file/folder names, especially when the project is already located in a very deep hierarchy.

Desireble would be something along the lines of this:

```
MyProject\
    MyCompany.MyProject.sln
    src\
        ConsoleApp\
            MyCompany.MyProject.ConsoleApp.csproj
```

In order to achieve this, I have to do the same repeating step over and over again

1. Create empty solution with only the projects name
2. Navigate to the solution folder, create a folder "src"
3. Create a project with only the projects type name (e.g. Ui, Frontend, Console..)
4. Rename project according to company naming guidelines
5. Rename assembly/namespace
6. Adjust namespace in files (okay, I got ReSharper, so this is quickly done).

Is there any way to automate this? Maybe with a custom wizard or extension?

Comment: Not really an answer ... but: About just one or two weeks ago we moved to [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). Yeah, it takes some time and nay, it won't solve all your problems but at the moment I'm quite confident that it has been worth it. Especially when it comes to folder hierarchy (and given that you are used to CMakes "style" of doing things) you have much more control.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi CMake sounds extremely promising, however my boss would definitely not agree with that. (He's more of a mouse/UI type of person)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own project layout template for Visual Studio by following the steps on MSDN on how to create your own [Project Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx).
After creating the template, you can create the deployment file, to use on all team member installations so that everyone has them.

This way you can define everything exactly how you want it to be and not have to go through all the steps that you mentioned.

Comment: I don't think this approach allows you to customize the name or organization of folders. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SideWaffle](https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle) and read through the [wiki](https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki) or other tutorials on creating your own packs and templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Nager.TemplateBuilder](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.TemplateBuilder) it is easy to design the project structure and you can start it as a console application.